# How to store/append/or CVS a *very* long list?

Tags: python, list

I've been trying to create a Python-based program that's continuously appending towards a list a long list of values (each one stored in its own element, of course) depending on the user's input on how big they would like these values to reach towards.

For example, if the user wants to generate a list with each element containing an element that's incrementing by +1, they can choose how long the list will be:

```
list1 = []

def addToList():
    length = int(input("Enter the total length you would like the list to reach: "))

    for i in range(length):
        print("i = ", i)
        list1.append(i)

    print(list1)

addToList()
```

Pretty easy. But what happens if the value stored to generate the length of the list is an *extremely* long one? Like 2143017345534564656949646943634964694649368496460342305694634954560464963045493543064369345324095834954395840584958439404095345093459031450345813498572130956134095861587345891234501356982356238945613249056134805613105314561345613048561340561348905613489561340756130456130845610289345723948723947239742983472984723047024734032453453513451345715345734505577 etc...

What would a beneficial way to compute a program that's able to create lists in this size?

I'm aware that just appending to list would not work as the program freezes (and takes up space in memory as well). Additionally, I've tried to use Numpy when declaring the size of the array before the values for each element are computed before they are appended to the list itself. But nothing seems to be working so far.

Is there also a way to be able to store the values to a CVS file *as* each element if being computed?

So that way as each value is actually they automatically saved to a file and *not* within the program itself (the program can just be used to calculate the values and transfer each one of them to a CVS file)?

The provided code is simple but the project I'm working it relies on this type of code but I know it can freeze up Python if one tries to achieve it.

Comment: By CVS, I assume you mean [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), not [CVS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System)?

Comment: if you want to compute only or do some run time calculation and not store these value then you can use a generator

Comment: You couldn't store this in a file either - storing an item of the size you propose, on the order of 2*(10^355), even if each item required 1 byte, would still require 2*(10^354) *terabytes*. That's over 2*10^300 times the amount of information **on the entire internet**

Comment: @user56700 no, it wouldn't help at **all**.

Comment: @sahasrara62 even if each iteration over that generator took 1 nanosecond, that would require 6*10^337 years. That is 4.6*10^327 times *the age of the universe*

Comment: What is the use case for this? As others have mentioned there is a limit to how much can be stored on a single file/computer. However, a generator might be appropriate. `range` already is a generator, actually. What are you doing with such large numbers?

Comment: @C_Z_ so, `range` is not a generator, it isn't even an iterator, actually. Here is how `range` works, if it were implemented in Python: https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/f4372d098913a1f66764833376f0e020 In any case, you *could* use a `range` object here potentially, but as stated above, if you need to actually store all the numbers or iterate over all of them, then you are going to run up to some physical constraints

Comment: Besides the physical constraints, there's the matter of the exceedingly long time it would take to process that many items even if they could be stored. Your question is moot.

Comment: @martineau I think processing time is a physical constraint :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: As Einstein said, time is an illusion. ;¬)